# Progress Dialog stops UI thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

I am showing some animation and making network request at the same time. Both are working fine independently. But when I try to place a **progress dialog** in asynctask the animation is not started until progress dialog until the **onPostExecute()**. My guess is that as the animation and progressdialog both run on the **UI thread** so only one can run at a time. Is there a way to show progress dialog and run animation at the same time both on the UI thread?

Here's my code:

```
public class DailyTarrotActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ImageView imageViewAnimation;
AnimationDrawable spinAnimation;
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
FlipImageView imageViewCard;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_tarrot);
    imageViewAnimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAnimation);
    imageViewAnimation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);
    imageViewCard = (FlipImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCard);
    spinAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewAnimation.getBackground();
    new DailyTarrotAsyncTask().execute();
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.d("start", "focuschange");
    if (hasFocus) {
        spinAnimation.start();
    }
}
public class DailyTarrotAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(DailyTarrotActivity.this);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        try {//just to mimic downloading behaviour
            thread.sleep(10000);//animation starts only after 10 secs
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(DailyTarrotActivity.this, "async task finished",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you see imageViewCard while progress Dialog is visible? I guess re-ordering the UI by imageViewCard .bringToFront() in doInBackground(), should do the trick.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. I can see the imageview. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. bring to front didnot help any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you start the animation(spinAnimation.start()) in doInBackground directly? Starting the animation from onWindowFocusChanged() callBack may be the cause.This call back is fired after the progressDialog hides.